# What file do you edit the most within your project?

Tags: file, project

Lately I have been editing a single CSS file over and over, and it got me to thinking what files do you touch most within your project?

For me it would be the `environment.rb`, or the `en.yml` file if I was coding in Rails.

I would like to update a list here with the most frequent files over time.

### Rails

- environment.rb
- en.yml

Comment: Web development or programming in general? For the latter, there'll be no common verbatim file names.

Comment: voting to close. discussion not a real question.

Comment: I fail to see how this question would be all that helpful to anyone.

Comment: It's not suppose to be helpful, it's just curiosity. I don't see why it's such a big deal. How are programming jokes helpful to anyone either?

Answer (score 7):

For me it's `TODO.txt`. Usually additions, unfortunately.

Comment: I was about to provide the same answer. +1 because this file exists in almost every project in any language I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

I edit en-US.yml all the time.  I'll probably have to edit it before I finish this post.  Yep, there I go.

Answer (score 0):

The only file I keep on editing the same amount in all projects is `build.xml` if using Ant I think ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've set up a script to extract revisions since the last tag from Mercurial, I usually update `CHANGELOG` or `CHANGELOG.txt` quite frequently for the benefit of those who downloaded a snapshot instead of cloning the repository.

Answer (score -1):

No file in particular. I'll code a lot in one file for a day or two, hitting a couple of other related files as I do, then move on the the next.

If I'm spending the majority of my time in a single file, I usually figure that I'm doing something wrong.